# In R, how can I convert a chr column that contains many different dates in different date formats (e.g., German, English, hourly)?

Tags: r, date, format

I have a dataframe `df` that contains multiple columns. One column `Dates` contains many string values of different date formats. It contains German date formats (i.e. 6. Juni 2022 or 5. Aug 2019), English date formats (i.e. Apr 5, 2019 or 4 Mar, 2019), it contains dates with in both formats without a year that need the current year added (i.e. Jan 2 or 15. März) and furthermore it also contains hours in both languages (i.e. 2 Std. or 3h).

I first want to transform the dates into one format (preferably English standard yyyy-mm-dd) and then add a new colum `Time_since` that calculates the hours since `Dates` until now. So for example, if I have the date 16. Mai 2023 (so yesterday in a German format) I want 24 in the new column (since I don't have specific times, I assume the full day 2023-05-17). If I have 10h or 10 Std. then I simply want a 10.

This is the `dput()` of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Dates = c("1h", "10 Std.", "Apr 5", "Dec 8, 2022", 
"May 30, 2019", "6. Juni 2021", NA, "15. März", "13. Aug. 2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

The output should be like this:

```
Dates        Time_since
1h           1
10 Std.      10
2023-04-05   1008
2022-12-08   3840
2019-05-30   25800
2021-06-06   17040
NA           NA 
2023-03-15   1512  
2019-08-13   24192
```

Any idea how I can combine this many transformations at once?

Answer (score 0):

You should translate words (months, hours) from German to English as much as possible.
To transform the dates into a standardized format and calculate the hours since the dates until now, you can use the lubridate package in R. If the dates have a specific time zone, you may need to adjust the code accordingly.

```
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(Dates = c("1h", "10 Std.", "Apr 5", "Dec 8, 2022",
                              "May 30, 2019", "6. Juni 2021", NA, "15. März", "13. Aug. 2019")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

parse_date <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("Juni", "June", x, fixed = TRUE)
  x <- gsub("März", "March", x, fixed = TRUE)
  x <- parse_date_time(x, orders = c("d. b", "d. B", "b d, y", "B d, y"))
  return(x)
}

df$Dates <- parse_date(df$Dates)
df$Time_since <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Dates), round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), df$Dates, units = "hours"), origin = "1970-01-01")), NA)

print(df)


       Dates Time_since
1       <NA>         NA
2       <NA>         NA
3       <NA>         NA
4 2022-12-08       3856
5 2019-05-30      34768
6       <NA>         NA
7       <NA>         NA
8 0000-03-15   17734768
9       <NA>         NA
```

I couldn't get to transform all dates perfectly, but I think this could at least help you in the right direction. Remember to change the 'origin' parameter accordingly.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got to the answer myself but maybe someone can shorten this code somehow. I just added many different steps and columns to get to the answer

```
#Convert h and Std.
df$Tw_hours <- as.numeric(gsub(" Std\\.", "", df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1))
df$Tw_hours <- as.numeric(gsub(" Std\\.|h", "", df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1))

# Load the lubridate package for date manipulation functions
library(lubridate)
# Convert rows with the valid date format to dates (English and German)
df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1_New_En <- parse_date_time(df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1, orders = c("dby", "mdy"))


# Specify the pre-specified date
specified_date <- as.POSIXct("2023-04-11")
# Calculate the hours between specified_date and Tw_Date_Tweet_1
df$Tw_Hours_Difference <- as.numeric(difftime(specified_date, df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1_New_En, units = "hours"))
#Add the pre-calculated values from h and Std.
df$Tw_Hours_Difference <- ifelse(is.na(df$Tw_Hours_Difference),df$Tw_hours, df$Tw_Hours_Difference)
#Get all remaining values without a year in a separate column
df$Tw_Remaining <- ifelse(is.na(df$Tw_Hours_Difference),df$Tw_Date_Tweet_1, NA)


# Add the year 2023 to non-NA values in Tw_Remaining column
df$Tw_Remaining <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Tw_Remaining),
                          paste(df$Tw_Remaining, "2023", sep = " "),
                          df$Tw_Remaining)
# Convert rows with the valid English date format to dates
df$Tw_Remaining_New <- parse_date_time(df$Tw_Remaining, orders = c("dby", "mdy"))
# Calculate the hours between specified_date and Tw_Date_Tweet_1
df$Tw_Remaining_New_Hours <- as.numeric(difftime(specified_date, df$Tw_Remaining_New, units = "hours"))
#Transfer dates into Tw_Date_Tweet_1_New_En
df$Tw_Hours_Difference <- ifelse(is.na(df$Tw_Hours_Difference), df$Tw_Remaining_New_Hours, df$Tw_Hours_Difference)

#Remove unnecessary columns
df <- select(df, -c(Tw_hours, Tw_Date_Tweet_1_New_En, Tw_Remaining, Tw_Remaining_New, Tw_Remaining_New_Hours))

print(df)
```